# Conditional partials in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

Angular novice here. I'm trying to wrap my head around the right way to accomplish a basic template issue.

I have a header, which should read “click here to log in” when the user is not logged in, and “Welcome, Dudefellah” (and associated Settings links and whatnot) when a user is logged in.

I've written a Service that is able to return a JSON bundle including a login state and username, but I don't know what “The Angular Way” to express: “if(auth.loggedin), output partials/header.html; else output partials/header_login.html”.

I’m unclear as to whether this logic would belong in the controller, or some kind of “auth” model, or even in the view (that can't be right, right?). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Within the controller once the login state is fetched create a scope variable `headerTemplate` and assign the name of the template depending on the login state

```
function MyCtrl($scope, loginService) {
    $scope.auth = loginService.getLoginState();
    $scope.headerTemplate = $scope.auth ? 'partials/header.html' : 'partials/header_login.html';
}
```

In in your markup

```
<div ng-include src="headerTemplate"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a sample angular application called [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) that does this really well.  They have a security service, then a toolbar partial and directive that shows things depending on the state.

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/common/security

from angular-app:

**src/common/security/login/toolbar.tpl.html:**

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
  <li ng-show="isAuthenticated()">
      <a href="#">{{currentUser.firstName}} {{currentUser.lastName}}</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-show="isAuthenticated()" class="logout">
      <form class="navbar-form">
          <button class="btn logout" ng-click="logout()">Log out</button>
      </form>
  </li>
  <li ng-hide="isAuthenticated()" class="login">
      <form class="navbar-form">
          <button class="btn login" ng-click="login()">Log in</button>
      </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**src/common/security/login/toolbar.js:**

```
angular.module('security.login.toolbar', [])

// The loginToolbar directive is a reusable widget that can show login or logout buttons
// and information the current authenticated user
.directive('loginToolbar', ['security', function(security) {
  var directive = {
    templateUrl: 'security/login/toolbar.tpl.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
      $scope.isAuthenticated = security.isAuthenticated;
      $scope.login = security.showLogin;
      $scope.logout = security.logout;
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return security.currentUser;
      }, function(currentUser) {
        $scope.currentUser = currentUser;
      });
    }
  };
  return directive;
}]);
```

Comment: Looks great, I’ll check it out.

Comment: Tis was perfect. It directed me directly to the answer! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which does wonders for conditional routing and for good infrastructure in general. You'll need to define two states:

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  ...
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        parent: account,
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "partials/header_login.html"
    })

    .state('auth', {
        parent: account,
        url: "/authorized",
        templateUrl: "partials/header.html"
    })

})
```

when you are back from your query, change state by $state.transitionTo('login') or ('auth') and the router will load the right template for you (and also the URL). in general its much better to use a good router as the basis of your app and not give ad-hoc solutions per each case. you could also read a page (I wrote) about it [here](http://lgorithms.blogspot.com/2013/07/angularui-router-as-infrastructure-of.html)

Comment: quick question- how to validate login if user directly visits a bookmark with url /authorized?

Comment: @Nikhil ui-router supports deep urls. all controllers will be called as usual